# Specify to categories of one object

Tags: grammar, phrases

I introduce two objects and need to tell how we refer each of the objects further in the text. How is it better to formulate it? Is the following correct:

> There are two person in the study. We refer to one person who works a lot as "hard-working" and another as "lazy".

Sorry for such a profound example. :)

**Update:** I modified the example such that the terms characterising each person is not self-explanatory.

> There are two persons in the study. We refer to one person who works a lot as P1, and another as P2.

The questions are:

1) Is it grammatically correct?

2) Is it concise and clear? If not, what should be the structure of the sentense?

Comment: Replace your double hyphens with *as*.

Comment: Are you asking how to introduce terminology?

Comment: Yes, I need to introduce two mutually excluding types of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways you could convey this information. The first sentence needs to be corrected

to

> There are two **persons** in the study.

or

> There are two **people** in the study.

The second sentence could be changed to:

> We will refer to the person who works a lot as the 'hard-working' person, and the other person as the 'lazy' person.

or

> The study focused on two people: a 'hard-working' person and a 'lazy' person.

or

> The two people in the study will be referred to as the 'hard-working' and 'lazy' persons, respectively.

or

> There are two persons in the study, the 'hard-working' person, and the 'lazy' person.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! Among your suggestions the variant that works the best is: "We will refer to the person who works a lot as the 'hard-working' person, and the other person as the 'lazy' person." Because in my case the categories are not self-explanatory as "hard-working" or "lazy". However, in what you suggested the word "person" is used many times. Is it possible to make it more concise?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you could make it more concise: "The two people in the study are labeled 'hard-working' and 'lazy'" is one example.